# pyplot and semilogarithmic scale: how to draw a circle with transform

Tags: matplotlib, geometry, logarithm

I want to have a circle in a plot made with pyplot, but I need to use a log scale on the x axis.

I do:

```
ax = plt.axes()

point1 = plt.Circle((x,y), x, color='r',clip_on=False, 
                    transform = ax.transAxes, alpha = .5)

plt.xscale('log')

current_fig = plt.gcf()

current_fig.gca().add_artist(point1)
```

As you see, I want the radius of the circle to be equal to the x coordinate.

My problem is that if I use, like written here, `transAxes`, then I get the circle to be actually a circle (otherwise it is stretched on the x and looks like an ellipse cut in half), but the x coordinate is 0. If, on the other hand, I use `transData` instead of `transAxes`, then I get the correct value for the x coordinate, but the circle is stretched again and cut in half.

I don't really mind the stretching but I don't like the cutting, I want it to be at least a full ellipse.

Any idea how to obtain what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to just use a plot marker instead of a `Circle`. For example:

```
ax.plot(x,y,marker='o',ms=x*5,mfc=(1.,0.,0.,0.5),mec='None')
```

This will give you a circle that will always look 'circular' and will be centred on the correct x,y coordinate, although its size will bear no relationship to the x and y scales. If you just care about the centre position then you can mess around with `ms=` until it looks right.

A more general way to do this would be to construct a new composite transformation for the circle - you should take a look at [this tutorial on transformations](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html). Basically, the transformation from figure to data space is constructed like this:

```
transData = transScale + (transLimits + transAxes)
```

where `transScale` handles any nonlinear (e.g. logarithmic) scaling of the data, `transLimits` maps the x- and y-limits of the data into the unit space of the axes, and `transAxes` maps the corners of the axes bounding box into display space.

You want to keep the circle looking like a circle/ellipse (i.e. not distort it according to the logarithmic scaling of the x-axis), but you still want to translate it to the correct centre location in data coordinates. In order to do that, you can construct a scaled translation, then combine it with `transLimits` and `transAxes`:

```
from matplotlib.transforms import ScaledTranslation

ax = plt.axes(xscale='log')
x,y = 10,0
ax.set_ylim(-11,11)
ax.set_xlim(1E-11,1E11)

# use the axis scale tform to figure out how far to translate 
circ_offset = ScaledTranslation(x,y,ax.transScale)

# construct the composite tform
circ_tform = circ_offset + ax.transLimits + ax.transAxes

# create the circle centred on the origin, apply the composite tform
circ = plt.Circle((0,0),x,color='r',alpha=0.5,transform=circ_tform)
ax.add_artist(circ)
plt.show()
```

Obviously the scaling in the x-axis is going to be a bit weird and arbitrary - you'll need to play around with how you construct the transformation in order to get exactly what you want.